# How on earth does this question have 2.7k views on day 1?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, views, hot-questions, answer-count

How come the views for this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/234657) is at 2,732 if it was only posted today? It has a lot of answers, too! Is this a bug or is this really happening? *How* has this happened?

> [image]

Comment: It was probably featured somewhere, e.g. In the "hot questions" list.

Comment: but there are 2732 view ,is that possible ? I never see before @Pëkka

Comment: Post in question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/234657/why-is-select-from-table-considered-bad-practice

Comment: I can't imagine there's even that many people on the whole internet.

Comment: It is in the "hot questions" list.  I thought about clicking on it myself, but I've seen this question and the answer to it so many times that I did not.  But I can see the appeal.  I believe the number.  (Did not click before reading your question, that is.  Now it has another view from me, and more views from other MSO users.)

Comment: We have even had questions on Security Stack Exchange with many thousand views in their first day - if they get on HN or reddit, or even Slashdot it is almost inevitable.

Answer (score 7):

This is entirely possible. It isn't extraordinary or a bug.

Ten answers is rather a lot, but it happens. As for the views, it's in our hot network questions list and enough people seem interested in it. By comparison, [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/733754/119760) on the hot questions list has 8,571 views and 16 answers.

> [image: the question being referenced is #2 on the list at the moment]

Answer (score 3):

No bug here. The question got into the [network hot questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), which gets shown on the sidebar of just about every page on the network. Since the sidebar list is about a quarter of the full list (chosen randomly), and at least the top five entries are always visible, there's a 5% chance that someone who loads a new page will see your question. 5% of a lot is still quite a lot, and many of those who see it go check out the question, hence lots of views.